# How can I transfer Steam game save files from one Mac to another?

Tags: steam, macos

I got a game in Steam, and because my computer was a little slow in terms of graphics, I bought a new top specked iMac to play the game. I took a backup of the old game and brought it over to the new computer, but should I not have installed the game on the new one first?

I am unable to move the game I have played (I have played for 24 hours) on the old computer, and when I start on the new one I am back to the start of the game.

How can I continue from the old game save?

Comment: I would say it is game specific.

Comment: Assuming you are using the same Steam account and own the game, first install the game. Then follow @VladislavToncharov's instructions to find the save file location of the game, if it even has one. Without knowing which game you are working with we cannot help you any further.

Comment: Game saves are generally not kept with the game files, they are usually in your user account folder, or documents folder etc

Comment: There's also the ability to sync your save files to steamcloud for games that support that.

Answer (score 5):

This process is very, ***very*** game-specific, as @Communisty mentioned in the comment section. There are a lot guides on moving and creating backups of game savefiles. The best way to get started is to search `<game name> save location` and copy saves from that location on your old Mac and then paste to that location on the new one.

Answer (score -1):

you could just copy the entire game over, all the files included.
and steam has an "add game" functionality which allows you to add any shortcut/application to steam in case steam does not register the game after you've copied it over

Comment: This would not work with many games. It may do the trick for Starbound, but most games store save files separately.

Comment: huh, oh okek, worked for KSP I dunno what he's transferring tho